# Use a Content File from a .NET Standard assembly in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard

I want to embed a file in a .NET Standard assembly and use it in XAML in a WPF app.

If you set the build action to `Resource` it is very easy to use the embedded file in other assemblies, but you have to use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">` and `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` to be able to use the `Resource` build action like so:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Image.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then you can use this Uri from another assembly:

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Resources/Image.png
```

as seen here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris

### My question:

If you want only `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` and don't want `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` then you have to use the `Content` build action, because it does not require WPF, as seen here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions

And use it like so:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Resources\Image.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then you should be able to use this Uri from another assembly:

```
pack://application:,,,/Resources/Image.png
```

as seen here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#content-file-pack-uris

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in PresentationFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in PresentationCore.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'TargetDefaultValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'pack://application:,,,/Resources/Image.png' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=BackgroundImage; DataItem='NavigationNode' (HashCode=663215); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource') IOException:'System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'resources/image.png'.
```

I have cleaned and rebuilt the whole solution.

What am I doing wrong?

*Important: I need to use a pack URI in xaml - too many to convert all existing code from xaml to cs!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference a content file that gets copied to the output directory, you could use a path rather than a pack URI. Try this:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($@"{System.AppContext.BaseDirectory}\Resources\Image.png",
    UriKind.Absolute));
```

If you still need to use a pack URI for some reason, replace `pack://application:,,,` with `pack://siteoforigin:,,,` in the path and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I know that. But I absolutely need to use a pack URI in xaml.

Comment: Why? There is no point of using a pack URI if you copy the contents to the output directory.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make sense if you develop a new app. But I am porting a .NET Framework app with hundreds of images that have a pack URI in xaml - and converting all that from xaml to `image.Source = new BitmapImage` would be a nightmare - I would much rather use a RegEx replace for all of them. Anyway, I found out that while `pack://application:,,,` doesn't work with `<Content>` but `pack://siteoforigin:,,,` works perfectly, so I can delete this question... or leave it for someone else with the same problem.

Comment: @Jinjinov: I added this in my answer in case you want to accept it.