# Cannot locate resource image WPF .NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I have a poject in .NET Framework and I ported to .NET Core, all the functionality is running ok, but for some reason some icon from resources are not loaded.
I have a tree and every item should have an icon, which I read and set to a property for that item. The image should be added when the object is created. So for this I have the following line to read the URI:

`return new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/{assemblyName};component/{path}", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`

When I pass the URI to BitmapImage, I receive the following error:
`System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'images/collapseddirectory_16x16.png'.'`

When I go to Edit item source properties, the image already have Buil Action set to Resource.

I have tried to use another image but the same result.

Comment: have you tried to change the option "copy to output directory"?

Comment: @Paulo Well the problem is that I cannot open the properties window for image,the properties window is empty

Comment: @Sipick Are you loading those images from another assembly, or why are you using the `{assemblyName};component` part of the Pack URI? Make sure the project file for that assembly has `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`.

Comment: As a note, specifying `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` is also pointless. A Pack URI is always absolute. Just remove that second constructor argument.

Comment: @Clemens The project where I have the class with this methos have <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> and it is a Class Library project.
The project (where I call this class where the images shoul be loaded), have <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61894060/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for help, the last link helped me, but also I needed to change from new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/{assemblyName};component/{path}");
to:
new Uri($"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/{path}");
And I needed to change the image Build Action to Content.

Comment: But as said, setting `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop"` on the class library project should also work.

Comment: @Clemens My bad here, I changed project settings and it is working.